# Makefile:270: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?). Stop

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

```
MAKEINFO = ${SHELL} /Users/mbingi/Summer/suricata-2.0.1/missing makeinfo
MANIFEST_TOOL = :
MKDIR_P = ./install-sh -c -d
NM = /opt/local/bin/nm
NMEDIT = nmedit
NVCC = 
OBJDUMP = false
OBJEXT = o
OTOOL = otool
OTOOL64 = :
PACKAGE = suricata
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT = 
PACKAGE_NAME = suricata
PACKAGE_STRING = suricata 2.0.1
PACKAGE_TARNAME = suricata
PACKAGE_URL =
```

**For the above make file code , I am getting the missing separator error for (PACKAGE = suricata) line.**

Comment: Which part of the error message do you not understand?

Comment: There are no rules in that makefile, only a few variables.

Comment: Go to line 270 (which is probably not in the snippet above). Chances are the line should begin with a tab, but it begins with some other whitespace, e.g. eight spaces. Fix that and try again. *Don't* ask us how to put a tab in a text file, or why your editor can't do it.

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dv71ghfff6v6wgd/AAAqiiGRGCh_RrwOidqSaafka/Makefile) This is Makefile I am using. I can't identify at line 270 (PACKAGE = suricata) what is exact error.

Comment: I just ran GNU make on it and it doesn't report this error. Which version of make are you using?  What does `make -v` say?

Comment: I am using "GNU Make 3.81"

Comment: bash-3.2# make -f Makefile
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in libhtp
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in htp
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in test
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in docs
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in src
Makefile:270: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
bash-3.2#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a slight mistake in the above `makefile` it should be `:=` instead of `=:`

Change `OTOOL64 = :` to `OTOOL64 :=` it will work fine